# New page of midlevel grouping in Active Reports v7

Tags: grouping, activereports

This has me stumped but then again, I haven't done reports in like 10 years.  We are using an old version, AR win 7.

I have groupings by state, Type A, County, Type B.  Boss wants it to kick the new county to a new page so I set the NewPage to AfterPrint for the group footer (totals).  Problem with that is, when it's the last county of the upper groups (State, Type A), those totals go on a new page but boss wants them on the same page of the last county.

I thought about changing the NewPage setting to BeforePrint on the County Group header, but then the state and type labels print on a page before the first county...want those on the same page too.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out.  Seems to work.

Removed the NewPage property setting on the report and set it in code....

```
Private Sub GroupHeader3_AfterPrint(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupHeader3.AfterPrint
    GroupHeader3.NewPage = SectionReportModel.NewPage.Before
End Sub
```

Then set the GroupKeepTogether = FirstDetail  on the two groupings above (State, Type A).

That seems to have done it.